# Multivariable logarithm limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I'm having trouble evaluating the following multivariable limit. I know the answer, but I'm not sure how to prove it.

$$\lim \limits_{x,y \to 0,0} \frac{\ln(1+x+y)}{x+y}$$

Thanks.

Comment: Apply $\ln(1+a)=a+o(a)$ with $a=x+y$ for $x,y$ sufficiently small.  We get $1$ at the end.

Comment: This is kind of a shot in the dark but, we want to observe the behavior of this as $x,y \to 0,0$. We know that $x+y = 0$ at $(0,0)$. Perhaps we could take $lim _ {a \to 0} \frac{ln(1+a)}{a}$.

Comment: take z = x + y. Can you prove that the limit for $ln(1+z)/z = 1$ when z $\rightarrow 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the function $\frac{\log(1+x+y)}{x+y}$ is not defined in a neighbourhood of the origin for the points such that $x+y=0$, thus the limit does not exist.

However we can extend the function defining $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$ by: $$f(x,y)=\left\{
\begin{array}{cl} 
\frac{\log(1+x+y)}{x+y} & x+y\neq0; \\ 
1 & x+y=0.\end{array}\right.$$

For the extended function we can set $x+y=z \quad z\to0$

$$\frac{\ln(1+x+y)}{x+y}=\frac{\ln(1+z)}{z}=\frac{z+o(z)}{z}=1+o(1)\to1$$